# Next larger element in generic tree

Tags: python-3.x, list, generics, tree, cp

I am trying to solve this code challenge:

> Find and return the next larger node in a generic tree given the root of the tree and an integer `n`.
>
> #### Input format
>
> The first line of input contains data of the nodes of the tree in level order form. The order is: data for root node, number of children to root node, data of each of child nodes and so on and so forth for each node. The data of the nodes of the tree is separated by space. The following line contains an integer, that denotes the value of `n`.
>
> #### Example
>
> Sample input:
>
> ```
> 10 3 20 30 40 2 40 50 0 0 0 0
> 21
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> 30
> ```
>
> The back-end already converts the input into a tree with `data` and `children` attributes. The root node and the value of `n` are passed as arguments to the function.

I decided to store all node and its data into a list. Here is my code:

```
def nextLargest(tree, n):
    li=[]
  
    def helper(tree):
        li.append([tree,tree.data])
        for child in tree.children:
            helper(child, n)
    li=sorted(li,key=lambda x: x[1])
    
    for ele in li:
        if ele[1] > n:
            return ele[0]
```

But it's not working: the `append` method is not working, as the list is always empty. Is it because I'm storing addresses? Where is the problem in my code?

I know its not best way to solve it but I'm kind of curious how to fix it.

Comment: How does that sequence of numbers represent a tree? I see no processing of that list of numbers and no creation of nodes in your code...

Comment: Input format :
The first line of input contains data of the nodes of the tree in level order form. The order is: data for root node, number of children to root node, data of each of child nodes and so on and so forth for each node. The data of the nodes of the tree is separated by space.  
The following line contains an integer, that denotes the value of n.

Comment: using that input of sequence of numbers levelwise tree is getting created on backend

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `helper` is not called. You need to do:

```
helper(tree)
li=sorted(li,key=lambda x: x[1])
```

The recursive call of `helper` has a second argument that shouldn't be there. It should just be:

```
for child in tree.children:
    helper(child)
```

With those changes the function will return the next largest node (if any). If you need to print the result, don't forget that it is a node instance, and you would need to get its data.

#### Optimising space

It should not be necessary to use O(n) auxiliary space. Try to do this without storing nodes in a list. You could for instance traverse the nodes with a generator.

Here is a spoiler solution:

> `def walk(tree):
>      yield tree
>      for child in tree.children:
>          yield from walk(child)
>
>  def nextLargest(tree, n):
>      return min(((node.data, i, node)
>                      for i, node in enumerate(walk(tree))
>                      if node.data > n),
>                  default=(0, 0, None))[2]`